# c program to display binary tree but it is not showing any output even it is not showing any error. whtat is the error in this program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct tree{char info;struct tree *left;struct tree *right;};
struct tree *root;
struct tree *stree(struct tree *root,struct tree *r,char info);
void print_tree(struct tree *root,int l);

int main(void)
{
  char s[80];
  root=NULL;
  do {
    printf("enter a letter:");
    gets(s);
    root=stree(root,root, *s);

  }
  while(*s); // <- ???
  print_tree(root,0);
  return 0;

}

struct tree *stree(struct tree *root,struct tree *r,char info;{ // <- ???
   if(!r) {
     r=(struct tree *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
     if(!r) {
       printf("out of memory \n");
       exit(0);
     }
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
    r->info=info;
    if(!root)
    return r;
    if(info<root->info)
    root->left=r;
    else
    root->right=r;
    return r;}if(info<r->info)stree(r,r->left,info);else 
    stree(r,r->right,info);return root;}
    void print_tree(struct tree *r,int l);
    {
    int i;
    if(!r) return ;
    print_tree(r->right,l+1);
    for(i=0;i<l;++i)
    printf(" ");
    printf("%c \n",r->info);
    print_tree(r->left,l+1);
    }
```

Comment: Well, did you step through the code with a debugger?  That is the first thing to do.  Leaning how to debug a program is just as important as learning the language. Please also try to indent code properly for ease of reading.

Comment: Q: What compiler and what debugger are you using?  The *FIRST* thing to try is to step through the debugger line by line, and make sure "everything looks OK"...

Comment: Your indentation is ...

Comment: What you posted so far is non-compilable. Any C compiler will refuse to compile this with an error message. Your claim that "it is not showing any error" is false.

Comment: Please indent your properly so it is more easily readable.

Comment: @user6362024 - I changed a little of the formatting, and flagged the first two bugs I noticed (an infinite loop, and a compile error).  That should get you started.  *IMPORTANT SUGGESTIONS*: 1) please change your indentation style, 2) please familiarize yourself with your system's debugger.

Comment: You did not compile, build or test this code.

Comment: First, Can't compile it.

Comment: What did you do, just attempt to manually transcribe the code from some book or site into this SO post?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is not the correct output is, because it is not been updated with the return value of `stree`.

E.g. `if(info<r->info)stree(r,r->left,info);` <-- It has been discarded return value.

Your code doesn't compile. So, I rewrite code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree { 
    char info;
    struct tree *left, *right;
};

struct tree *stree(struct tree *root, char info);//no need `struct tree *r`
void print_tree(struct tree *root, int level);

int main(void){
    struct tree *root = NULL;//It does not need to be in a global variable
    char letter;

    for(;;){
        printf("enter a letter:");
        if(EOF == scanf("%c", &letter) || letter == '\n')//don't use `gets`
            break;
        scanf("%*[^\n]");//clear upto newline
        scanf("%*c");
        root = stree(root, letter);
    }
    print_tree(root, 0);
    //deallocate
    return 0;

}

struct tree *stree(struct tree *root, char info){
    if(!root){
        struct tree *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
        if(!r){
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        r->right = r->left = NULL;
        r->info = info;
        return r;
    }
    if(info < root->info)
        root->left = stree(root->left, info);
    else if(info > root->info)
        root->right = stree(root->right, info);
    else
        ;//root->right = stree(root->right, info);
    return root;
}

void print_tree(struct tree *r, int level){
    if(!r) return ;

    print_tree(r->right, level + 1);

    printf("%*s%c\n", level, "", r->info);

    print_tree(r->left, level + 1);
}
```